# Tile large raster file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, tiling

I have a raster file of 1600 km2 with cell size 2x2 m that I need to polygonize and the script takes a really long time to finish (>25 minutes, but I don't know how long it effectively takes, since I had to kill the task)

How can I make smaller tiles of the large raster in QGIS? Let's say we make 16 tiles, so 4x4 tiles. What is the best method for that in QGIS 3.3+?

Comment: I'm not sure about QGIS,  but `rasterio` offers quite some possibilities in terms of windowing into rasters and processing them window by window. Check https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/windowed-rw.rst ... But this begs the question are you OK with using python?

Comment: If you're familiar with the [CEFRL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages), I would say I don't even have half of level A1. I recognize Python when I see it, but that's about it. Although, as I start working more with GIS, I intend to get back into learning Python more. I'll see whether I get it to work for my simple task whatsoever. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS is using gdal_polygonoze https://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html for creating the polygons. It does not have on option for selecting a region of the input raster to be processed. It means that you must make a selection as a separate step. I would recommend to use gdal_translate https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html and virtual raster output https://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html for that.

You seem to have an image with 40000 x 40000 pixels. If you want to have a try with a 10000 x 10000 image clipped from the top-left corner use this command:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -srcwin 0 0 10000 10000 big_input.tif small_test.vrt
```

Once you have found the proper size for gdal_polygonize you will only need to slide the window with x and y offsets

> **-srcwin** xoff yoff xsize ysize:
>       Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying based on pixel/line location.

VRT is just an instruction about how to read the original physical file. For such a big image it is also essential that the source image is tiled. Check the situation with gdalinfo and if the image is not tiled already, make a physical geotiff copy with gdal_translate first.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co TILED=YES input.tif tiled_output.tif
```

You may also want to create a compressed output, see the options from https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html.